# Flagging a question/answer which contains some login info is right?

Tags: support, revisions-list

That happened to me for the second or the third time now. When I am checking new questions, I saw a question (generally trying to login to a website, browser manipulation questions etc.) which contains some login data. I warned the OP about the situation.

If the OP recognizes it in time, he may have a chance to edit the question and remove it. Otherwise, login info can be viewable in the question edit history if the edit is done after the 5 minutes grace period.

*Flagging the question for mod attention is right thing to do* if OP edited the question after the grace period and login data still can be reachable from edit history? Can mods do anything about that? By basic logic tells me that a mod can not do anything to change a record in that style.

There was a flag about a  similar situation that I raised 18 days ago and it still is in active state.

Note: Users sharing their login data are generally new users and probably do not know that their edit history is kept.

Comment: Ohhh, I know I would not be the first to ask.

Comment: I had the same thing a couple of months ago and ended up in a discussion with a mod, so I remembered...

Comment: Well, my flag is still active, standibn there for 18 days (: